# How do you submit objects with a many to many relationship using the Entities Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, many-to-many

This is a follow up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304916/need-help-using-entities-for-asp-net-mvc-2-framework) I asked yesterday. I've tracked down exactly the issue I think is causing me grief and I think I can explain the situation with more clarity.

I just can't seem to figure out how to write objects with a many to many relationship to a SQL database using the Entities Framework in a C# ASP.NET MVC 2 Project.

Here is what I tried:

I have a very simple database with only two tables. Hobbies with columns name and description and People with columns for first and last names. I create a default .edmx with everything selected. (Both also use an int as a primary key (HobbieID, PersonID) which I set in the database designed to be auto incremented.)

I can then use the following code successfully:

```
SampleEntities entities = new SampleEntities();
Hobby h1 = new Hobby() { Name = "Tennis", Description = "Not golf" };
Person p1 = new Person() { First = "Jack", Last = "Black" };
entities.Hobbies.AddObject(h1);
entities.People.AddObject(p1);
entities.SaveChanges();
```

Sure enough both are added to the database correctly. Now where it breaks.

I add another table the database called JunctionHobbiesPeople which has two columns (HobbieID, PersonID) which I make foreign keys using the relationships pop up window in the database designer. I then add the JunctionHobbiesPeople table to the entities designer (via right click update, using the GUI) and it graphically shows a correct many to many relationship.

Then I try the following code:

```
SampleEntities entities = new SampleEntities();
Hobby h1 = new Hobby() { Name = "Tennis", Description = "Not golf" };
Person p1 = new Person() { First = "Jack", Last = "Black" };
p1.Hobbies.Add(h1);
entities.People.AddObject(p1);
entities.SaveChanges();
```

The first error I get is about DefiningQuery. I can fix that by just deleting all of the DefiningQuery elements from the xml in the code behind the .edmx file. Speaking of which, as a side question, what is that element for - should I not delete it?

After that error goes away I get the following error:

```
InnerException  {"Invalid object name 'ModelStoreContainer.JunctionHobbiesPeople'."}    System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}
```

Any idea's what I'm doing wrong? Do I have to inset them in a special order? How can I get many to many relationships to correctly be written to the database?

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: I'll ask you the same question I asked on your previous question: Do you have a *real* PK on JunctionHobbiesPeople ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - A real PK? The columns show up with the key symbol to show they've been marked as a primary key and it auto increments when I added data to the tables before the Junction table existed. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @evan - I think Craig is talking about in the database, not just in the EF designer. What if you do just the two tables Hobbies and People and then put an many-to-many association between them?

Comment: @Craig - I finally get what you mean!! I marked both keys in the junction as PKs and now it works. I'm an idiot! :)

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you've already solved this since you posted in 2010, anyhow this may help someone else :)
I had the same problem using MVC3.
My original edmx file had a row that looked like this:

```
<EntitySet Name="StockUpdates" EntityType="SwebotModel.Store.StockUpdates" store:Type="Tables" store:Schema="dbo" store:Name="StockUpdates"/>
```

To solve this i changed it into this:

```
<EntitySet Name="StockUpdates" EntityType="SwebotModel.Store.StockUpdates" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo"/>
```

Removing store:Name and the "store:" before Schema.